# Prev/Next buttons are under image inside slide in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, css, slider, swiper.js

I have multiple instances of slider on my site, but one in particular is giving me headaches.
Consider webshop and all sliders (top sellers, recommended, etc.) are loaded with Swiper slider, only on iOS (iPhone 5, 6 & 7) there seems to be a problem inside a slider that is called in bootstrap modal as prev/next buttons are under slides - you can see them but you can clearly see they are under the slides or the whole wrapper of slider, and the funny thing is that it's working on iPhone 4.

I tried changing z-index on slider initialization but that didn't change anything, I can see z-index is changed in inspect element but in iPhone 5, 6 & 7 nothing is changed.

I tried updating navigation on slider initialization and also nothing changed.

I rewrote whole initialization code and also, it didn't fix it.

Does anybody have any clue what to try next? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem is somewhat weird, but after adding

```
-webkit-transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);
```

to prev and next buttons it's magically fixed.

What caused this issue in the first place is still unknown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying with z-index, make sure the element is positioned (try position tweaks). Also see if there is any overflow property set, that is resulting in this behaviour.

Comment: After checking css, prev/next buttons are positioned absolute and there is no overflow property set, only on parent container and unsetting it breaks slider.

Comment: Can you share the css of the button and parent?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/25z7eu8d/) is a fiddle for CSS.

Comment: Also I think it's worth noting that I'm changing z-index with jQuery with "$('.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next').css('z-index', '1060'); $('.swiper-wrapper').css('z-index', '1');" and not directly in CSS.

Comment: I found a hotfix as setting -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1) fixes the problem.

Comment: Oh Nice. You may post yourself the answer